# GLib convert GString from UTF-8 to UTF-16/32 possible?

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, glib

The GLib provides the struct *GString* which is encoded in UTF-8.

I know there are functions to convert a single *gchar* (UTF-8) to *gunicode* (UTF-32) or *gunicode2* (UTF-16).

But if I want to convert a complete GString into UTF-16/UTF-32, is this possible?

If not, I don't see the point in storing the majority of text in UTF-8 strings but you can only convert single chars into UTF-16/UTF-32 and are forced to use gunicode-arrays, when GString encapsulated those nasty arrays. And you wouldn't be able to use all the string functions provided by the glib on your UTF-16/UTF-32 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLib provides several [Character Set Conversion](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html) functions.  If you're confused about them not taking a `GString`, you can get at the underlying pointer and length using the `str` and `len` fields.

Comment: Yes, I was confused that they dont take `GString`. So I have to convert the `str` field and reassign it with the output of e.g. the `convert`-function. But there i get a `gchar*`, with `gchar` in the documentation stated is a UTF-8 char, I dont get it how GLib can store a UTF-16/32 char in a `gchar`. Is GLib  then just taking 2 `gchar` for on UTF-16/32 char? How do I tell `g_printf` that the following `gchar*` is encoded in UTF-16/32?

Comment: A single code point can require multiple `gchar`s.  Almost every function in C (especially in glib or libraries which use it) is either completely unaware of the character set or assumes it to be UTF-8.  You don't tell them what encoding the buffer you pass them is, you pass them UTF-8 and, if you need to convert the result to some other character set you do so.

Comment: ah, many thanks, that clearified alot. Short version: GLib uses UTF-8. But if you need somewhere else other charset's, GLib can do it for you.